# How to make instance of mxml and pass parameters?

Tags: apache-flex, dynamically-generated, togglebutton

i want to create instance of mxml (in my case EventList) and pass parameters. My Event List is a list of panels so I want to pass parameters and generate dynamically n number of panels (n-parameter to pass). I have the main app where I have toggle button bar when I click on the first I want for example to generate 3 panels (n=3) on the second button 20 panels (n=20) etc.
How can I do this?  How can I pass n and what is the best way to show the list? I whant to generate the list when I click on the toggle button!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use xmlnamespace(xmlns) to access the mxml file in your source folder.I created an application which includes xmlns="*" (* means you can access any component in the source folder)to access the myEvenList component. i pass the n value here itself.Check out the example.HTH.

togglePanelCount.mxml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mx:Application name="ToggleButtonBar_toggleOnClick_test"
    xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"
    layout="vertical"
    verticalAlign="top"
    backgroundColor="white" xmlns:eventList="*">                                 <mx:ToggleButtonBar id="toggleButtonBar"
                    dataProvider="{viewStack}" /><mx:ViewStack id="viewStack"
        width="100%"
        height="100%">
    <eventList:myEventList n="5" id="List1"/>
    <eventList:myEventList n="20" id="List2"/>
 </mx:ViewStack></mx:Application>
```

myEvenList.mxml

> ```
>           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" creationComplete="createPanels()"><mx:Script>
>     <![CDATA[
>         import mx.controls.Alert;
>         import mx.containers.Panel;
>         public var n:int;
>         public function createPanels():void{
>          Alert.show("in create panel");
>          for(var i:int =0 ;i<n;i++){
>           var panel:Panel = new Panel();
>           panel.title = "panel"+(i+1);
>           panelList.addChild(panel);
>           }
>           }
>     ]]>
> </mx:Script><mx:VBox id="panelList" /></mx:Canvas>
> ```

PS:Having n as a public attribute itself gives you a way of passing the count of panels.Even in the mx:Script tag in the application, you can instantiate the myEventList object and set the value of n instead of using mxml tags.